# How to read a csv with unknown no of columns and compare it with another and retrieve values

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv `Neighbours.csv` which has disease name and patients who have that disease:

```
Chondromalacia patellae,alex,maggie,bob
Hypogonadism,Williams,alex
and so on....
```

Another csv `Similarityscores.csv` which has Patient name and his score:

```
Williams,0.0
alex,1.0
bob,2.0
maggie,0.5
and so on....
```

Now my desired output Disease name and sum of scores of the patients who have that disease:

```
Chondromalacia patellae,3.5
Hypogonadism,1.0
```

I have tried processing `Neighbours.csv` first, but since the number of patients who have the disease is unknown, I am not able to proceed further.

Comment: Please show your code and effort. [ask]

Comment: Doesn't sound to me like you need the `Neighbours.csv` file to get the information you need.  What is it's purpose (i.e how to you envision it being used)? In what way does not knowing the number of patients in advance stop you from writing some code?

Comment: my_cols = ["Disease","Neighbour1","Neighbour2","Neighbour3","Neighbour4","Neighbour5","Neighbour6","Neighbour7","Neighbour8"]
my_pd=pd.read_csv("Neighbours.csv",names=my_cols,engine='python')
print(my_pd)

Comment: Neighbours.csv is needed to find out the patients who have that particular disease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you have no idea how many patients for a specific disease, right?, If so, I have a little idea:

1:You load the csv and get patients column for a disease, something like this

```
import pandas as pd

data_Neighbours = pd.read_csv("Neighbours.csv")
patients = data_Neighbours["patients"]
```

2:Then you get a list of patients:

patients = [patellae,alex,maggie,bob......jack]

You can now get the count of the patients.And do some operation on this patients list for your needs.

Comment: Thanks Alex , i think this might help :)